# Parse decodeURIComponent JSON string with Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json

I have a "deep" JSON string that I need to pass as GET vars in a URL. It looks like the following:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "prune": true,
    "returnFields": ["gf", "gh", "gh", "rt"],
    "orient": "split"
  },
  "indicators": [{
    "type": "beta",
    "computeOn": "gf",
    "parameters": {
      "timeperiod": 5,
      "nbdevup": 2,
      "nbdevdn": 2,
      "matype": 0
    }
  }, {
    "type": "alpha",
    "computeOn": "gf",
    "parameters": {
      "timeperiod": 30
    }
  }]
};
```

When encoding using `jQuery.param`, the result is as follows:

```
var recursiveEncoded = jQuery.param(body);
console.log(recursiveEncoded);
meta%5Bprune%5D=true&meta%5BreturnFields%5D%5B%5D=gf&meta%5BreturnFields%5D%5B%5D=gh&meta%5BreturnFields%5D%5B%5D=gh&meta%5BreturnFields%5D%5B%5D=rt&meta%5Borient%5D=split&indicators%5B0%5D%5Btype%5D=beta&indicators%5B0%5D%5BcomputeOn%5D=gf&indicators%5B0%5D%5Bparameters%5D%5Btimeperiod%5D=5&indicators%5B0%5D%5Bparameters%5D%5Bnbdevup%5D=2&indicators%5B0%5D%5Bparameters%5D%5Bnbdevdn%5D=2&indicators%5B0%5D%5Bparameters%5D%5Bmatype%5D=0&indicators%5B1%5D%5Btype%5D=alpha&indicators%5B1%5D%5BcomputeOn%5D=gf&indicators%5B1%5D%5Bparameters%5D%5Btimeperiod%5D=30
```

Which is decoded to the following:

```
var recursiveDecoded = decodeURIComponent( jQuery.param(body) );
console.log(recursiveDecoded);

meta[prune]=true&meta[returnFields][]=gf&meta[returnFields][]=gh&meta[returnFields][]=gh&meta[returnFields][]=rt&meta[orient]=split&indicators[0][type]=beta&indicators[0][computeOn]=gf&indicators[0][parameters][timeperiod]=5&indicators[0][parameters][nbdevup]=2&indicators[0][parameters][nbdevdn]=2&indicators[0][parameters][matype]=0&indicators[1][type]=alpha&indicators[1][computeOn]=gf&indicators[1][parameters][timeperiod]=30
```

If just using a serialized string result on the server leaves the string as the key in a key value pair:

```
"query": {
    "{\"meta\":{\"prune\":true,\"returnFields\":[\"gf\",\"gh\",\"gh\",\"rt\"],\"orient\":\"split\"},\"indicators\":[{\"type\":\"beta\",\"computeOn\":\"gf\",\"parameters\":{\"timeperiod\":5,\"nbdevup\":2,\"nbdevdn\":2,\"matype\":0}},{\"type\":\"alpha\",\"computeOn\":\"gf\",\"parameters\":{\"timeperiod\":30}}]}": ""
  },
```

My backend processing is done with Python. What modules exist to convert the above result to a `dict` resembling the original object?

Comment: You'd probably be better off sending it as JSON and then deserializing it into an object in Python. Less messy that way.

Comment: The requirement is to send as GET request. I've already done the POST request which can handle a JSON string.

Comment: You can send an Object in jQuery using the GET method without using `$.param()`. If you make sure your data also ends up as JSON on the Server, as a result to your AJAX request, you should be fine. Worst case scenario, you have to set your `dataType` to `'json'`.

Comment: @strimp Then URL encode a serialized JSON string and send it as a single GET parameter. Same difference. I never said anything about POSTing. :) Is there some requirement that it be split into different query string values that is beyond your control?

Comment: @haliphax when passing as one string, it is received as the key in a key value pair (don't ask me). See edit.

Comment: @strimp099 I didn't mean pass it by itself... set it as the value, and specify the key. `"key=" + yourSerializedValue`, etc... I suppose you could use `JSON.stringify`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: @PHPglue this is for an API where I cannot guarantee users will be using jQuery.

Comment: I see your edit - but your string is the VALUE in a key value pair. The key is "query"...

Comment: @haliphax right I see what you mean, that could work. I can use Python's `json.loads` method to parse the string server side. Leave an answer and if works will upvote and accept.

Comment: The site is yelling at me for having an extended discussion in comments, so I'll just say this: Yep, that's absolutely what you could do (and what I would recommend). :)

Comment: The data must be normalized before it goes to the Server anyways. To send it back to the Client see see this - https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, since we hashed it out in the comments, I'll post the answer here for posterity.

Use a combination of `JSON.stringify` on the JavaScript side to serialize your data structure and `json.loads` on the Python side to deserialize it. Pass the serialized structure as a query string parameter ("query" in your example) and then read the value from that query string parameter in Python. Huzzah!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: There is no need to `JSON.stringify()` JSON before sending it via any AJAX method in jQuery.

Comment: True, if you're using jQuery. I was a bit confused, as the OP had said something about jQuery not being a guarantee for each client (though jQuery is used in the example code).

Comment: Is OP saying the Client is sending a string as GET data, instead of GET data itself? Why would OP expect the Server to receive strings like that on his Server? Require your Clients to send POST or GET data, not crazy strings.

Comment: You lost me. If you mean they should split the structure so that it takes up many different keys/values in a query string, I don't see why that is necessary. If it represents a single object, passing it as a single query string key/value pair seems just fine. There's no rule or HTTP spec that says you need to do otherwise. Data serialization is not uncommon, especially with complex, nested structures.